# How to avoid NaN being rendered in audio player duration?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nan

I built a cool little audio player and am having issues with data fetching. The page renders before the audio file in the return statement src, here:

```
<audio ref={audio} src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wfhmtvbc5two1wa/1-allen_2991.ogg" alt="oops, something went wrong..."></audio>
```

The `NaN` shows up in the duration time represented by this line:

```
{/* duration */}
        <div className={styles.duration}>{(duration && !isNaN(duration)) && calculateTime(duration)}</div>
```

This above line of code isn't preventing the `NaN`, so I tried my hand at fetching in the `useEffect`, shown below but that has made this issue worse.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
--------------------

useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wfhmtvbc5two1wa/1-allen_2991.ogg").then(
            res => setData(res.loadedmetadata)
        )
    })
--------------------

 <audio ref={audio} src={data} alt="oops, something went wrong..."></audio>
```

If anyone could give it a look and point me in the right direction, id be very grateful. Below I will provide all the code for my component.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import styles from '../styles/AudioPlayer.module.css';
import {BsArrowClockwise} from 'react-icons/bs';
import {BsArrowCounterclockwise} from 'react-icons/bs';
import {BsPlayCircleFill} from 'react-icons/bs';
import {BsPauseCircleFill} from 'react-icons/bs';

const AudioPlayer = () => {
  //state
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  //refs
  const audio = useRef();
  const progressBar = useRef();
  const progressBarAnimation = useRef(); 

  //effects
  useEffect(() => {
    const seconds = Math.floor(audio.current.duration);
    setDuration(seconds);
    progressBar.current.max = seconds;
  }, [ audio?.current?.loadedmetadata, audio?.current?.readyState ]);
 
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wfhmtvbc5two1wa/1-allen_2991.ogg").then(
            res => setData(res.loadedmetadata)
        )
    })
    

  //functions & Handlers
  const calculateTime = (secs) => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    const returnedMinutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : `${minutes}`;
    const seconds = Math.floor(secs % 60);
    const returnedSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : `${seconds}`;
    return `${returnedMinutes}:${returnedSeconds}`;
  }

  const isPlayingHandler = () => {
    const prevValue = isPlaying;
    setIsPlaying(!prevValue);
    if (!prevValue) {
      audio.current.play();
      progressBarAnimation.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying);
    } else {
      audio.current.pause();
      cancelAnimationFrame(progressBarAnimation.current);
    };
  };

  const whilePlaying = () => {
    progressBar.current.value = audio.current.currentTime;
    progressBarValueTicker();
    progressBarAnimation.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying);
  };

  const progressHandler = () => {
    audio.current.currentTime = progressBar.current.value;
    progressBarValueTicker();
  };

  const progressBarValueTicker = () => {
    progressBar.current.style.setProperty('--seek-before-width', `${progressBar.current.value / duration * 100}%`);
    setCurrentTime(progressBar.current.value);
  }

  const backwardFifteen = () => {
    console.log(progressBar.current.value)
    progressBar.current.value = Number(progressBar.current.value) - 15;
    console.log(progressBar.current.value)
    progressHandler();
    
  };

  const forwardFifteen = () => {
    console.log(progressBar.current.value)
    progressBar.current.value = Number(progressBar.current.value) + 15;
    console.log(progressBar.current.value)
    progressHandler();
  };

  return(
    <>
      <div>
         {/* eventually, a loop component tag will replace the below line to loop all audio file title and descriptions*/}
      </div>
      <div className={styles.audioWrapper}>
        {/* eventually, a loop component tag will replace the below line to loop all audio files*/}
        <audio ref={audio} src={data} alt="oops, something went wrong..."></audio>
        {/* <audio ref={audio} src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wfhmtvbc5two1wa/1-allen_2991.ogg" alt="oops, something went wrong..."></audio> */}
        <button className={styles.sideButtons} onClick={backwardFifteen}><BsArrowCounterclockwise />15</button>
        <button className={styles.playPauseButton} onClick={isPlayingHandler}>
          { isPlaying ? <BsPauseCircleFill /> : <BsPlayCircleFill /> }</button>
        <button className={styles.sideButtons} onClick={forwardFifteen}>15<BsArrowClockwise /></button>

        {/* current time */}
        <div className={styles.currentTime}>{calculateTime(currentTime)}</div>

        {/* progress bar */}
        <div>
          <input type="range" ref={progressBar} className={styles.progressBar} onChange={progressHandler} defaultValue='0'/>
        </div>

        {/* duration */}
        <div className={styles.duration}>{(duration && !isNaN(duration)) && calculateTime(duration)}</div>  
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    const onLoadedMetadata = ()=>{
        const seconds = Math.floor(audioPlayer.current.duration);
        setDuration(seconds);
        progressBar.current.max = seconds;
    }
```

```
<audio ref={audioPlayer} src={audio_file} preload="metadata" onLoadedMetadata={onLoadedMetadata}></audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `NaN` is rendered is because `NaN` is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value and will return the value immediately in the expression below.

```js
(duration && !isNaN(duration)) && calculateTime(duration)
// `NaN && !isNaN(NaN)` returns `NaN` because it is falsy
```

Simply removing the first condition will avoid `NaN` being rendered.

```js
!isNaN(duration) && calculateTime(duration)
```

However, the actual `duration` value will still be `NaN` and nothing will get rendered. This is because when you check for the `audio.current.duration` value inside the `useEffect` the duration hasn't actually updated yet.

To solve this issue, you can listen to the `onDurationChange` event in the `audio` element and update the `duration` state variable when it gets triggered.

```js
// Convert the `useEffect` code into a function instead
const onDurationChangeHandler = (e) => {
    const seconds = Math.floor(e.target.duration);
    setDuration(seconds);
    progressBar.current.max = seconds;
};
```

```js
<audio
    ref={audio}
    src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wfhmtvbc5two1wa/1-allen_2991.ogg"
    alt="oops, something went wrong..."
    onDurationChange={onDurationChangeHandler}
></audio>
```